# Issue with running multiple processes on a single webcam with Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-4, camera, real-time

I have a Python program that utilizes threading to run multiple processes on a single webcam. The code works perfectly fine on my laptop, where it can run different processes simultaneously on one camera. However, when I try to run the same code on my Raspberry Pi 4, it does not work at all... I don't understand why it's not working.

```
import threading
from Head import HeadTracking
from Hand2 import HandTracking
from Monitoring import video_stream

if __name__ == '__main__':
    head_tracking = HeadTracking()
    hand_tracking = HandTracking()
    video_stream = video_stream

    head_thread = threading.Thread(target=head_tracking.run)
    hand_thread = threading.Thread(target=hand_tracking.run)
    video_thread = threading.Thread(target=video_stream)

    head_thread.start()
    hand_thread.start()
    video_thread.start()

    head_thread.join()
    hand_thread.join()
    video_thread.join()
```

Comment: are you saying that you get no errors?